# Setting prior probabilities in Naive Bayes MultinomialNB

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, naivebayes, grid-search

I do not believe this is a duplicate because neither [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248583/how-can-the-prior-probabilities-manually-set-for-the-naive-bayes-clf-in-scikit-l?rq=1) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896367/how-to-specify-the-prior-probability-for-scikit-learns-naive-bayes) answers the question I will be asking.

First, `MultinomialNB` does have a `class_prior` parameter (not an attribute) as seen in this snippet from the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.get_params):

> Parameters:
>
> alpha : float, optional (default=1.0)
>
> ```
> Additive (Laplace/Lidstone) smoothing parameter (0 for no smoothing).
> ```
>
> fit_prior : boolean, optional (default=True)
>
> ```
> Whether to learn class prior probabilities or not. If false, a uniform prior will be used.
> ```
>
> class_prior : array-like, size (n_classes,), optional (default=None)
>
> ```
> Prior probabilities of the classes. If specified the priors are not adjusted according to the data.
> ```

Second, the following code and its output corroborates this:

```
NB_cls= MultinomialNB(alpha= 0.1, fit_prior = True, class_prior = [.2, .8])

NB_cls.get_params()
```

> > {'alpha': 0.1, 'class_prior': [0.2, 0.8], 'fit_prior': True}

However, the following code, aiming to set up a gridsearch to tune the hyperparameters of a `MultinomialNB` classifier gives an error message that says `class_prior` is not a parameter:

```
alphas = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]
p_grid_NB = {'alpha': alphas, 'fit_prior' : [True, False], 'class_prior ' : [None, [.1,.9],[.2, .8]]}

NB_cls= MultinomialNB()

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = NB_cls, param_grid = p_grid_NB, scoring = 'roc_auc', cv = 5)
grid.fit(Train_X, Train_y)
```

> ValueError: Invalid parameter class_prior  for estimator
>   MultinomialNB. Check the list of available parameters with
>   `estimator.get_params().keys()`.

There is nothing wrong with the data input to the classifier.  Here is working code with the same data (which has also been used without problems in grid searches with `MLPClassifier` and `SGDClassifier`) :

```
nb_cls = MultinomialNB()
nb_cls.fit(Train_X, Train_y)

y_hat = nb_cls.predict(Test_X)
print accuracy_score(Test_y, y_hat)
```

> > 0.73125

**Question**: What am I missing about setting this parameter?

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: You have left a space in your 'class_prior' in p_grid_NB. You have defined it as 'class_prior '. Notice the space at the end.

Comment: Thank you for your kind correction Mr. Kumar

Comment: Please close this question if your issue has resolved. If you have any other doubt, post a new question.

Comment: How do I close the question?  Could not find anything in the documentation.